# Error in RShiny UI.r: argument "variable" is missing, with no default

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny, rpart

Trying to create a ui.r file for showing a Pert Distribution

I got the following error: Error in ui.r: argument "variable" is missing, with no default

The common fix for this that I have seen is to remove unnecessary commas and I believe I have done this.

```
server <- function(input, output){

  BS = function(n, births, cat2, statusmin, statusmode, statusmax, impactmin, impactmode, impactmax){
    d1 = births*cat2*rpart(n,statusmin,statusmode,statusmax)*rpart(n,impactmin,impactmode,impactmax)
    return(d1)
  }

output$plotCall <- renderPlot({
  n = input$n
  births = input$births
  cat2 = input$cat2
  statusmin = input$statusmin
  statusmode = input$statusmode
  statusmax = input$statusmax
  impactmin = input$impactmin
  impactmode = input$impactmode
  impactmax = input$impactmax

  gg <- ggplot(data.frame(BS()), aes(x = BS))
  gg <- gg + geom_histogram(aes(y = ..density..),color = "black", fill = "white",
                            binwidth = 2 * IQR(BS) / length(BS)^(1/3))
  gg <- gg + geom_density(fill = "steelblue", alpha = 1/3)
  gg <- gg + scale_x_continuous(labels = comma)
  gg <- gg + theme_bw()
  plot(gg, labels = TRUE, conf.level = .8)
  }

)
}

ui <- shinyUI(fluidPage(

  titlePanel("ROI"),

  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      numericInput('n', 'Number of Simulations', 1000, min = 1, max = 1000, step = 1),
      numericInput('birth', 'Number of Births', 6811, min = 1, max = 10000, step = 1),
      numericInput('cat2', 'Percentage of Category II Strips', 0.84, min = 0.01, max = 1, step = 0.01),
      numericInput('statusmin', '% Status Min', 0.1, min = 0.01, max = 1, step = 0.01),
      numericInput('statusmode', '% Status Most Likely', 0.3, min = 0.01, max = 1, step = 0.01),
      numericInput('statusmax', '% Status Max', 0.4, min = 0.01, max = 1, step = 0.01),
      numericInput('impactmin', '% Impact Min', 0.2, min = 0.01, max = 1, step = 0.01),
      numericInput('impactmode', '% Impact Most Likely', 0.4, min = 0.01, max = 1, step = 0.01),
      numericInput('impactmax', '% Impact Max', 0.64, min = 0.01, max = 1, step = 0.01)


    ),

    mainPanel(
      textOutput("BScall"),
      hr(),
      tabsetPanel(
        tabPanel("Calls", plotOutput("plotCall",width="100%"))
      )
    )
  )
))


shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

I am trying to get a histogram of the results of d1.

Comment: I am trying to get a histogram of the results of d1.

Comment: what are you expecting `d1` to represent? calling `rpart()` returns an object of class `rpart`, and the way you have passed arguments to `rpart()` is not a valid call. Review the [documentation](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/rpart/versions/4.1-15/topics/rpart) to see how to enter a formula for rpart. It will return a model object, so including it in a multiplication call will not work. In addition, You have `BS()` defined as a function, but in your call to `ggplot()` you have not given any arguments to your function `BS`, therefore it will not be able to calculate anything.

Answer (score 0):

I've found a couple of issues in this code. As Wil pointed out in the comments, you define `BS` as a function with several arguments, but when you call `BS()` you're not assigning any arguments to it.

So, the first change I made was to define a variable called `result_d1` that receives the output from `BS(n, births, cat2, statusmin, statusmode, statusmax, impactmin, impactmode, impactmax)`. Then I passed this variable to `ggplot`:

here: `gg <- ggplot(data.frame(result_d1), aes(x=result_d1))`;

and here:

```
gg + geom_histogram(aes(y = ..density..),color = "black", fill = "white",
                              binwidth = 2 * IQR(result_d1) / length(result_d1)^(1/3))
```

Another issue is that you call `input$births` but the ID for your `numericInput` is "birth". I changed this to "births".

Even after these fixes, we have issues with the function `rpart`, as Wil pointed out as well. I'm not familiar with this function nor its package, but since you said that you want to plot a Pert Distribution I'll use the function `dpert` from the `mc2d` package to get the values for the histogram. I don't know if this is exactly what you want, but with a working code that uses this `dpert` you can make the necessary changes to use the `rpart` function.

One last thing, I changed `scale_x_continuous(labels = comma)` to `scale_x_continuous(labels = scales::comma)`.

Here's the full code:

```
server <- function(input, output){

  BS = function(n, births, cat2, statusmin, statusmode, statusmax, impactmin, impactmode, impactmax){

    x.status <- seq(statusmin, statusmax, length.out= n)
    x.impact <- seq(impactmin, impactmax, length.out= n)

    d1 = births*cat2*
      dpert(x.status, min=statusmin, mode=statusmode, max=statusmax)*
      dpert(x.impact, min=impactmin, mode=impactmode, max=impactmax)

    return(d1)
  }

  output$plotCall <- renderPlot({
    n = input$n
    births = input$births
    cat2 = input$cat2
    statusmin = input$statusmin
    statusmode = input$statusmode
    statusmax = input$statusmax
    impactmin = input$impactmin
    impactmode = input$impactmode
    impactmax = input$impactmax

    result_d1 <- BS(n, births, cat2, statusmin, statusmode, statusmax, impactmin, impactmode, impactmax)

    gg <- ggplot(data.frame(result_d1), aes(x=result_d1))
    gg <- gg + geom_histogram(aes(y = ..density..),color = "black", fill = "white",
                              binwidth = 2 * IQR(result_d1) / length(result_d1)^(1/3))
    gg <- gg + geom_density(fill = "steelblue", alpha = 1/3)
    gg <- gg + scale_x_continuous(labels = scales::comma)
    gg <- gg + theme_bw()
    plot(gg, labels = TRUE, conf.level = .8)
  }
  )
}

ui <- shinyUI(fluidPage(

  titlePanel("ROI"),

  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      numericInput('n', 'Number of Simulations', 1000, min = 1, max = 1000, step = 1),
      numericInput('births', 'Number of Births', 6811, min = 1, max = 10000, step = 1),
      numericInput('cat2', 'Percentage of Category II Strips', 0.84, min = 0.01, max = 1, step = 0.01),
      numericInput('statusmin', '% Status Min', 0.1, min = 0.01, max = 1, step = 0.01),
      numericInput('statusmode', '% Status Most Likely', 0.3, min = 0.01, max = 1, step = 0.01),
      numericInput('statusmax', '% Status Max', 0.4, min = 0.01, max = 1, step = 0.01),
      numericInput('impactmin', '% Impact Min', 0.2, min = 0.01, max = 1, step = 0.01),
      numericInput('impactmode', '% Impact Most Likely', 0.4, min = 0.01, max = 1, step = 0.01),
      numericInput('impactmax', '% Impact Max', 0.64, min = 0.01, max = 1, step = 0.01)


    ),

    mainPanel(
      textOutput("BScall"),
      hr(),
      tabsetPanel(
        tabPanel("Calls", plotOutput("plotCall",width="100%"))
      )
    )
  )
))


shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

And the output:

[image]